# Angular 17 Prerendering (Static Site Generation (SSG)) inconsistent result when using with Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm pre-rendering an angular site with 100+ pages and each page has a simple call to Firebase to get data and then display them on the page. I put all routes in routes.txt

```
 "prerender": {
   "routesFile": "routes.txt"
 },
```

It worked well until I realized that some of pre-render pages had empty content. Every time I run the prerender, it has random results, some pages works some pages don't. if I only have 2-5 routes, the pre-render works fine and consistent. My suspicious is that when pre-render, angular just blasts calls to Firebase and doesn't wait until Firebase returns the data, hence the empty pre-render page.

Is there a way to set pre-render to do it synchronously or a way for prerender to wait until each page is finished?

Thank you so much in advance